# accounts.google.com redirected you too many times in Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am working on social login in Laravel.
When passing parameter for identifying sign in and signup, it occurs error.

### *"accounts.google.com redirected you too many times."*

### Without a parameter, it works well.

These are my router.

```
Route::get('/login/google', 'Auth\LoginController@google')->name('login.google');   //working well

Route::get('/login/google/{method}', 'Auth\LoginController@google')->name('login.google'); //not working
Route::get('/login/google/redirect', 'Auth\LoginController@googleRedirect');
```

This is my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    private $googleSign = '';

    //public function google()         //working well
    public function google($method)    //not working
    {
        $this->googleSign = $method;
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }
    
    public function googleRedirect()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
    }
```

This is my view.

```
<a href="{{ route('login.google', 'signin') }}">
    Sign in with Google
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a route issue.

```
Route::get('/login/google/{method}', 'Auth\LoginController@google')->name('login.google');
Route::get('/login/googleRedirect', 'Auth\LoginController@googleRedirect');
```